# Where can I find a dictionary for homonyms?

Tags: dictionaries, homophones, homonyms

I want to know where I can find a dictionary that I can look up homonyms of a word. For instance if I type in *alien* it will show me the word *salient*. That dictionary should base on the sound itself, not just the word list. There are new words that these lists don't contain, like *pwn* (it will sound similar to *cow*).

Comment: You can find innumerable [lists of homonyms](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_true_homonyms) on the internet, as you are clearly aware, but you're not looking for homonyms (*salient* is not a homonym for *alien* by any stretch of definition). Perhaps a rhyming dictionary would be a good start, though you'd have to find one that listed slant rhyme, internal rhyme, etc. That said, any such reference will lag innovation in the English language, by definition, so I'd be surprised if you found one which includes "*pwn*" and words like it.

Comment: I'll also offer a word of warning: pronunciation is one of the most widely-varying aspects of the English language, so words that rhyme or sound alike to you may not sound alike to a Scot or a Texan. For example, around here *pwn* is pronounced like *own* (/ˈpoʊn/ or pohn), and doesn't sound anything like *cow*.

Comment: You are right. What I am looking for is actually a rhyming dictionary. The word *salient* /seliənt/ isn't a homonym of *alien* /eliən/?

Comment: I found a rhyming dictionary which may suit your need, posted as an answer. To answer your question about *salient* vs *alien*, no, as I said, those two words are definitely not homonyms. [Homonyms](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homonym) can be defined in several ways; they may have the *exact same* pronunciation ("*homo-*" means "*same*") or the *exact same* spelling, or ideally both, to be what's called a "true homonym". But words which simply sound *similar* are not termed "*homonyms*".

Comment: So they are just rhythm to each other?

Comment: Even saying "they rhyme" a stretch, because "rhyme", unqualified, typically means "syllabic rhyme", i.e. the last syllable of each word sounds the same. There are other types of rhyme, like "slant rhyme", where the leading syllables sound similar, or "forced rhyme", where the sound match is imperfect, etc. Anyway, because you're  not looking for typical, traditional (syllabic) rhymes, I had to find a special rhyming dictionary which included entries for at least slant rhyme, but even that may not be enough, because I think you're looking for a more general idea of "words which sound similar".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a resource request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled for rhyming dictionaries which include (at a minimum) *slant rhyme*, and came across the site [B-Rhymes](http://www.b-rhymes.com), which does, indeed, give "*salient*" as a match for "*alien*" (but does not, as I guessed, have an entry for *pwn*).

Comment: It does have apps for iOS and Android. Great! Thanks for your help.